# Regular expression to match string that groups together with dot

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

Hi I am trying to create a regular expression with the rules:

- portion before '.com' or '.edu' can only have at most 10 alphabets
- if this portion does not exist, then it should only return 'com'

For example,

`'stack.com'` is valid

`'stackoverflow.com'` is not valid as it has more than 10 alpha before .com

`'.com'` is not valid while `'com'` is valid

Here is what I have so far:

```
regex = r'^([A-Za-z]{,10}\.)?(com|edu)'

re.match(regex, 'com')
```

I am trying to group the portion before `(com|edu)` together, so that if it does not exist, then the `.` will also not be there.

Comment: `$` means "here must be the end". I think you want `?`, which means "optional".

Comment: Oops sorry, i meant `?`

Comment: Cool. So what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: like @rici, said, you have answered the problem already?

Comment: `.com` is still valid, but should be invalid

Answer (score 0):

Given the condition "`.com` is not valid while `com` is valid", I think your expression is the right one and you just have to do some processing afterwards:

```
import re
full_string = """stack.com
stackoverflow.com
.com
foo.edu
com
bar
sitcom
sit.com"""

regex = r'^([A-Za-z]{,10}\.)?(com|edu)$'
for base, domain in re.findall(regex, full_string, re.MULTILINE):
    if base not in (".", ""):  
        print(base.strip("."))
    else:   # nothin before com/edu
        print(domain)
```

Edit: if you want to completely exclude `.com` (and not change it to `com`) you can still go with:

```
regex = r'^(?:[A-Za-z]{1,10}\.)?(?:com|edu)$'
print(re.findall(regex, full_string, re.MULTILINE))
```